# JavaScript function to display a dynamic message in a <div> container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this class exercise for a while now and i cant figure out whats up with it. First off i have dug through my book over and over again with no luck on finding any helpful answers. Then I Googgled the hell out of it which was a wild chase id rather not experience again. Also i don't want any one to think I'm just looking for someone to do my work. i legitimately need some help and guidance.

What I need to display is;

1. JavaScript function to display a dynamic message in a  container.
2. JavaScript function to change the color of the scroll bar.
3. JavaScript function to use a drop-down list to link to new Web pages.
4. JavaScript function to display the date the Web page was last modified and a copyright message in a  container.

Here is what i have so far when i Validate it i get this message:

***Line 26, Column 30:** document type does not allow element "h1" here
    displayDate.innerHTML = "Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We h…
✉
The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

***Error Line 44, Column 34:** document type does not allow element "h6" here
displayCopyRight.innerHTML = "The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<…
✉
The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).*

```
<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Oakwood Elementary School</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--hide from older browsers-->
function coountDown(){
    var today = new Date()
    var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
    dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
    weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
    newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
    dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
    monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate+1)
    yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2014")
    year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

    var ColumbusDay = new Date("October 8, 2014")
    var daysTooGo = ColumbusDay.getTime()-today.getTime()
    var daysToColumbusDay = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24))

    displayDate.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We have "+daysToColumbusDay+" days until Columbus Day.</h1>   
    }

function scrollColor() {
        styleObject=document.getElementsByTagName('html').style
        styleObject.scrollbarFaceColor="#fbb04"
        styleObject.scrollbarTrackColor="#ffe700"
}

function loadInfo(myForm) {
    var menuSelect=myForm.Menu.selectedIndex
    var menuUrl=myForm.Menu.options[menuSelect].value+".html"
    window.location=menuUrl
    }

    functions copyRight() {
var lastModDate = document.lastModified
var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
displayCopyRight.innerHTML = "<h6>The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<br />Copyright Oakwood Elementary School"+"<br /> This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</h6>"
}


</script>
<style type="text/css">
.center {
    text-align:center;
    }

table {
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    }
.cell-width {
    width: 50%;
}

.left-align {
   width: 50%;
   left: 0;
   }

.right-align {
   width: 50%;
   right: 0;
   text-align: right; 
   } 

</style>
</head>
<body onload="scrollColor(); countDown(); copyRight()">
<div class="center">
<p><img src="chapter9Oakwood.jpg" alt="oakwood banner" width="750" height="120" /></p>
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">OAKWOOD ELEMENTARY SCHOOL</p>
<img src="hrzntlrule.jpg" width="700" height="5" alt="hr" />
<div id="displayDate">
</div>
<img src="hrzntlrule.jpg" width="700" height="5" alt="hr" /> </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Oakwood Village School Board</p>
    <p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">The Oakwood Village School Board will have monthly meetings on the third Tuesday of the month this fall. Meeting days are September 18, October 16, November 19, and December 18, 2012. All meetings will start promptly at 7:30 p.m. and adjourn by 9 p.m. Meeting days for the spring semester will be determined at the December meeting.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Morning drop off and afternoon pick up</p>
<p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">Please remember to enter the school drop off area from the south entrance and exit out the north drive way. As always, please watch for children walking to school.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Fall Fund Raiser</p>
<p style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:12pt">This fall, Oakwood Elementary School will have a flea market. We are seeking donations of usable items that can be sold at the flea market. Volunteers are needed to help with setup, sales, and post flea market clean up. Mike's Stop and Shop will serve hot dogs, hamburgers and refreshments.</p>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right-align"><img src="school-house_left.gif" alt="school" width="160" height="139" /></td>
    <td class="left-align">
          <img src="school-house_right.gif" alt="school" width="160" height="139" />
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <form id="announceMenu" action=" ">
      <p style="font-weight:bolder">
       Select an item from the list to see other current announcements:
         <select name="Menu" onchange="loadInfo(this.form)">
           <option>Select an information item</option>
           <option value="chapter09fundraiser">October Fundraiser</option>
           <option value="chapter09pto">October PTO </option>
           <option value="chapter09tests">State Achievement Test</option>
         </select>
      </p>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14pt">Attendance Policy:
    <span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:8pt">Please call in your child's attendance at 555-555-5555 x2205.</span>
    </p>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<div id="displayCopyRight">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, "<!--hide from older browsers-->" = 1997

Comment: Yeah, sadly there is a lot of out dated material in my text books.

Comment: From what I understand, your code works the way you want, but it's not validated (by something like http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Yes thats why im getting frustrated. when i try to load the page in either Google Chrome, Google Chrome Canary, or Internet Explorer the functions are not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is full of typos. You need to debug it in a browser. You can use firebug in firefox, or the build-in debugger of Chrome - press F12 to open it. If you want to use IE for that, god help you (especially if you have

A few of the errors I spotted:

1) typos: coountDown, daysTooGo, functions instead of function

2) `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array. So you should `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` if you want the first element. I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, but you probably want to apply the style to the body (`document.body`).

3) `displayDate.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We have "+daysToColumbusDay+" days until Columbus Day.</h1>`: you forgot to close the string.

4) don't forget the `var` when you create a variable, like you did with `styleObject`.

You should also consider having your code code-reviewed. Ideally by somebody that can sit with you and go through the code, but you can always try [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Of the many things I saw: unless you really know what you're doing, use `;`. And even if you know what you're doing, use them.

As for the `h1` and `h6` the validator is complaining about, you can always use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).

Comment: *Face Palm*
Cant believe i missed those errors. Thanks So much now that i have made those corrections the page works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging on your code.

Mostly you were victim of simple typos.

I saw nothing wrong with your technique, except that you have been using a textbook from the late 90's. You are not to blame for having followed the examples given, but a few things have changed since.

The few points you might want to correct:

- use `;` to terminate statements. Though it is theoretically possible to do without, it can cause rare but painful bugs (usually when a typo changes the meaning of your code). You can see semicolons as a safety net to avoid painful consequences of typos.
- rework your event handler code. Right now it works, but not for the reasons you might expect.

The date computation is a bit messy, but now that it displays properly you should have little trouble correcting it.

To avoid such frustrations in the future, I advise you to invest some time getting acquainted with the developper tools of your favourite browser.

Unfortunately, each browser implements its own flavour of dev tools, so I can't be more specific, but they all offer about the same services.
They are relatively explicit and you should have little trouble understanding how they work.

The console will display all the errors, and the debug tab will allow you to examine the contents of your variables, set breakpoints, etc. That is a massive time-saver once you get used to it.

```
<!--hide from older browsers--> // <-- obsolete
function countDown(){ // <-- typo corrected
    var today = new Date()
    var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
    dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
    weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
    newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
    dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
    monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate+1)
    yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2014")
    year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

    var ColumbusDay = new Date("October 8, 2014")
    var daysToGo = ColumbusDay.getTime()-today.getTime() // <-- typo corrected
    var daysToColumbusDay = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24))

    var displayDate = document.getElementById ('displayDate'); // <-- grab the element from its ID
    displayDate.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+". We have " // <-- trouble with date bits
                          + daysToColumbusDay+" days until Columbus Day.</h1>";  // <-- missing " added
    }

function scrollColor() {
        styleObject=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style // <-- array index added
        styleObject.scrollbarFaceColor="#fbb04"   // <-- IE specific style elements
        styleObject.scrollbarTrackColor="#ffe700"
}

function loadInfo(myForm) {
    var menuSelect=myForm.Menu.selectedIndex
    var menuUrl=myForm.Menu.options[menuSelect].value+".html"
    window.location=menuUrl
    }

    function copyRight() { // <-- typo corrected
var lastModDate = document.lastModified
var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
displayCopyRight.innerHTML = "<h6>The URL of this document is "+document.URL+"<br />Copyright Oakwood Elementary School"+"<br /> This document was last modified "+lastModDate+".</h6>"
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot! I appreciate the quick and precise answers from you guys. If you cant tell by now I'm a "Noob" to HTML and JavaScript. Any and all Tips you are willing to share would help me get on the right track.